# If else argument not working?

Tags: java, android, if-statement, jsoup

I am having a problem where an if else argument is only carrying out one of the arguments the last one.

I have this argument where if the conditions are between a certain time then jsoup should parse one set of data and if the time variable is outside the set of times then jsoup should parse a different set of data but it is always only parsing the last set.

I cant see where I have made the mistake but any input on the possible cause of this is really appreciated.

```
Calendar firstLimit= Calendar.getInstance();
firstLimit.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
firstLimit.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
firstLimit.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

Calendar secondLimit= Calendar.getInstance();
secondLimit.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 06);
secondLimit.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
secondLimit.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

Calendar currentTime=Calendar.getInstance();

Document docWeather1;

try {
    //Current weather from Met Office
    Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect("http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/val/wxfcs/"
            + "all/xml/3604?res=daily&key=2dd5950b-91e1-4671-9d83-625f2ae9cbf5")
        .timeout(10000)
        .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
        .execute();

    int statusCode = response.statusCode();

    if(statusCode == 200) {
        String xml = Jsoup.connect("http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/val/"
                + "wxfcs/all/xml/3604?res=daily&key=2dd5950b-91e1-4671-9d83-625f2ae9cbf5")
            .timeout(10000).get().toString();//Turns document into a string ready for parsing                       
        docWeather1 = Jsoup.parse(xml, "", Parser.xmlParser());

        if(currentTime.before(firstLimit) && currentTime.after(secondLimit)){

            String weatherType = docWeather1.select("Rep:eq(0)").first().attr("W");
            arr_data.add(weatherType);
            String tempDayMax = docWeather1.select("Rep:eq(0)").first().attr("Dm");
            arr_data.add(tempDayMax);
            String tempDayFeelLike = docWeather1.select("Rep:eq(0)").first().attr("FDm");
            arr_data.add(tempDayFeelLike);
            String windSpeed = docWeather1.select("Rep:eq(0)").first().attr("S");
            arr_data.add(windSpeed);
            String windDirection = docWeather1.select("Rep:eq(0)").first().attr("D");
            arr_data.add(windDirection);
            String pricipProb = docWeather1.select("Rep:eq(0)").first().attr("Ppd");
            arr_data.add(pricipProb);

            System.out.println("Current Weather Night Data Collected and Stored");
        } else {
            String xml1 = Jsoup.connect("http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/val/"
                                        + "wxfcs/all/xml/3604?res=daily&key=2dd5950b-91e1-4671-9d83-625f2ae9cbf5").timeout(10000).get().toString();//Turns document into a string ready for parsing                     
            docWeather1 = Jsoup.parse(xml1, "", Parser.xmlParser());

            String weatherType = docWeather1.select("Rep:eq(1)").first().attr("W");
            arr_data.add(weatherType);
            String tempDayMax = docWeather1.select("Rep:eq(1)").first().attr("Dm");
            arr_data.add(tempDayMax);
            String tempDayFeelLike = docWeather1.select("Rep:eq(1)").first().attr("FDm");
            arr_data.add(tempDayFeelLike);
            String windSpeed = docWeather1.select("Rep:eq(1)").first().attr("S");
            arr_data.add(windSpeed);
            String windDirection = docWeather1.select("Rep:eq(1)").first().attr("D");
            arr_data.add(windDirection);
            String pricipProb = docWeather1.select("Rep:eq(1)").first().attr("Ppd");
            arr_data.add(pricipProb);

            System.out.println("Current Weather Data Day Collected and Stored");
        }}else{
        System.out.println("received error code : " + statusCode);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}   

return arr_data;// return ArrayList from here
```

Comment: Well, when you have code like `}}else{` I'm not surprised something goes wrong...Have you checked the values associated with the `if` conditions via debugging?

Comment: If firstLimit is lower bound of the time range, then your before and after are the wrong way around.  As Zong Zheng Li says, if you formatted and indented o=your cope properly, the mismatched braces would stand out.

Comment: Use [extract method](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html) pattern to make this code readable

Comment: You have two if/else statements. Which one are you referring to?

Comment: I'm sorry about the indentation, that has come from myself quickly adding subtracting braces to find the solution, lazy. slap!. @Tanis.7x It is the inner if/else statement that does not work.

Comment: At what time were you testing this? That would be the expected behavior during most hours of the day...

Comment: I was testing this part last night but it was returning the Daytime summary

Comment: It looks like you can only test your app before 6PM.  Otherwise the first IF fails.  After 6PM = Miller Time!

Comment: It appears that I may have reverted to you great guys and girls here a bit to quickly. I was testing this last night after being awake for 36 hours (learning to program is my past time for long night shifts), after properly formatting it and tricking the app in to believing it was mid afternoon all now seems ok and I get the results I want. Thank you for all your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statement will return `true` and execute from the first block only if you run the program between 6 AM and 6 PM, since you are comparing the current time to those times. Try running the program during the day and you will get different results. If that was not the expected functionality, then there is another problem.